# If field is empty, then 10 postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to count price of all books. I need to make sure that if field is empty (it is NULL), then Book's value is 10. I have tried this:
`SUM(CASE WHEN Value = NULL THEN 10 ELSE Value END) as main_value`

But this doesn't do anything. It counts the sum fine, but when it finds empty field (null), it does not use value 10 in calculations.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare with `null` you need to use `is null`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Value is NULL THEN 10 ELSE Value END) as main_value
```

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to treat NULLs as 10s then [COALESCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) will do the trick:

> The `COALESCE` function returns the first of its arguments that is not null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null.

So you could:

```
sum(coalesce(Value, 10))
```